# How do I insert tabulation inside VS Code snippet?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, eslint, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

I have a code snippet in VS Code, looks like this

```
"JS arrow function": {
    "scope": "javascript, typescript",
    "prefix": "af",
    "body": [
        "const ${1:name} = (${2:props}) => {",
        "   $3",
        "}"
    ],
    "description": "Create arrow function"
}
```

I want to have `tabulation` before the `$3` tab stop, but VS Code shows an error :

**Invalid characters in string. Control characters must be escaped.**

At the same time putting `4 spaces` before `$3` works just fine, but I need `tabulation` exactly for my eslint config.

Is there a way to put `tabulation` there?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`\t`

That is the tab character escaped.

```
"JS arrow function": {
    "scope": "javascript, typescript",
    "prefix": "af",
    "body": [
        "const ${1:name} = (${2:props}) => {",
        "\t$3",
        "}"
    ],
    "description": "Create arrow function"
}
```